# Is there a notion of p-forms for $p=\infty$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

On infinite-dimensional manifolds, is there a sensible notion of p-forms with infinite p? Of volume forms? Is there a version of Stokes' integration formula?

Comment: dupe: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76117/infty-forms-and-infty-plectic-geometry?rq=1

Comment: @July: The link covers part of my question. Nothing about volume forms and integration.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9501075.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9203026.pdf